# What is the best way to determine if CurrentUser is System Account?

Tags: 2010, development, spuser

Traditionally I use:

```
if (web.CurrentUser.Name == "System Account")
```

Is there a possibility the System Account Name could be something other then "System Account".  Is there a more reliable way to check if CurrentUser is the System Account?

This is using SharePoint 2010.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To check if the Current User is system account you can use

```
if (web.CurrentUser.ID == web.Site.SystemAccount.ID)
```

SystemAccount is a property of SPSite object which gets the System Account of the site collection

Answer (score 8):

```
SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.ID == SPContext.Current.Site.SystemAccount.ID
```

This method is suitable?

Comment: Yes except SPContext is null for me this in this case so I had to go with the SPWeb object from the event properties to grab the CurrenUser

Answer (score 0):

Although question is about Sharepoint 2010, if anyone wants to find out the same in the newer versions, we have a direct approach

SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.UserToken.IsSystemAccount

a boolean flag denoting if the current logged in user is a system account or not

Answer (score -5):

Yes actually you can.

- Go to central administration

  1. Click on Security on the left
  2. Click on "Specify web application user policy"
  3. Click on the account you want to check on
  4. Check or uncheck the "Choose System Settings" option with "Account Operates as System"

Comment: -1 Unfortunately you appear to be answering the wrong question